# Undefined variable: page in /home/xoxo/shipper-panel.php on line 88

Tags: php

I keep receiving the error: Undefined variable: page in

This is The code

```html
if (isset($_GET['page'])){
  
 $file="inc/" . $page . ".php" ;
 if (file_exists($file)) {include ($file) ;}
}
else {
 include("inc/default-shipper.php");
}
?>
```

line 88 is :

```html
$file="inc/" . $page . ".php" ;
```

Comment: Please i need help ,

Comment: You forgot the line where you assign $_GET to the local var. Although it's better left defunct, because local file inclusion vulnerability.